# laravel select certian column of table with query on relation table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

A user can send a parameter for search  it can be city name or hotel's name.
I want to search that in hotel table and city table then and I want to send back only hotel name and city name in any result in response.
with my query it only return name of hotel but city's data is null, why?
How can I handle this?

Hotel and city have relation

In Hotel Model I have:

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
}
```

In city model:

```
public function hotel()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Hotel::class);
}
```

My query in related controller:

```
$hotels = Hotel::with('city')->select('name')->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->target . '%')
                ->orWhereHas('city', function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->target . '%');
                })
                ->orderBy('id')
                ->take(10)->get();
return response()->json(['result' => $hotels]);
```

and response is:

```
{"result":[{"name":"venus","city":null}]}
```

Comment: You are only selecting the `name`, in order to load the `city` relationship you have to include the `city_id` in your select. `->select('name', 'city_id')`

Comment: yes . thankyou . is it possible to get only name  of city... it already give me full data of city relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be more clear and faster:

```
$searchName = $request->target;

$hotels = Hotel::select('hotel.name as name', 'city.name as city')
            ->leftJoin('city', 'city.id', 'hotel.city_id')
            ->where('hotel.name', 'like', '%' . $searchName . '%')
            ->orWhere('city.name', 'like', '%' . $searchName . '%')
            ->orderBy('hotel.id')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();

return ['result' => $hotels]; //Laravel decode to Json if the request AJAX
```

Relations are good to use for simple and small queries.

Comment: why it say Table 'hotel.city' doesn't exist

Comment: In Laravel 5.7 and < used hotels named table, in Laravel 5.8 hotel. The table with the city should also be called correctly.

Comment: i changed hotel to hotels and city to cities its fine now